# JSON parsing using StAXON - XMLStreamException when there is a : character in element name

Tags: java, json, parsing, stax

We are using StAXON (due to its performance via StAX processing) to parse json input which contains colon(:) as element name. Colon is valid element name in JSON but while parsing via StAXON we are getting exception (XMLStreamException).

It works if I use namespaceSeparator as '\0', like `new JsonXMLConfigBuilder().namespaceSeparator(Character.MIN_VALUE)`. But this just changes the namespace separator.

My Question/Doubt:

1. Is it safe to do this? Are there chances of getting issue(s)
2. Is there a way to ignore colon while parsing (reading/writing) JSON?
3. Is there any other alternative to StAXON to parse JSON based on events like StAX parsing is done for XML.

**Sample Input** : `{"cust:person":{"name":"John Doe","phone":"555-1111"}}`

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Unbound prefix: cust
at de.odysseus.staxon.base.AbstractXMLStreamScope.verify(AbstractXMLStreamScope.java:212)
at de.odysseus.staxon.base.AbstractXMLStreamScope.setStartTagClosed(AbstractXMLStreamScope.java:234)
at de.odysseus.staxon.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.ensureStartTagClosed(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:191)
at de.odysseus.staxon.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.readStartElementTag(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:272)
at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.readStartElementTag(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:93)
at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:202)
at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:153)
at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:183)
at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:153)
at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:183)
at de.odysseus.staxon.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.initialize(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:216)
at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.initialize(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:87)
at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:78)
at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(JsonXMLInputFactory.java:150)
at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(JsonXMLInputFactory.java:45)
at JsonXml.main(JsonXml.java:27)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Colon is a legal name character in case the parser is not namespace aware. You should be able to turn off namespace awareness on the underlying XMLInputFactory (don't know the details of StAXON).

Comment: thanks for your response. It was indeed a good idea and I explored this option, however it seems that XMLInputFactory is not exposed in StAXON, so moved forward with the JsonXMLConfigBuilder().namespaceSeparator(Character.MIN_VALUE). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It’s safe to do this but it’s probably not what you want. Since StAXON tries to treat JSON like XML, you should give the library what it wants: A namespace for the „cust“ prefix. Read about [StAXON‘s conventions here](https://github.com/beckchr/staxon/wiki/Mapping-Convention).

To declare a namespace:

```
new JsonXMLConfigBuilder().namespaceMapping(„cust“, „http://example.com/ns/cust“)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did read about StAXON conventions, and also understand that StAXON treats json like xml (though that is not the case). Hopefully, StAXON will improve their library further to provide more support for json rather than restricting it like xml. For anyone looking for the approach - I moved forward with the JsonXMLConfigBuilder().namespaceSeparator(Character.MIN_VALUE). Thanks